# How do I clone a Windsor Container for a sub component

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

We have a boot loader which loads a whole pile of sub-components (separate dlls). The boot loader inserts lot of basic services in the castle container which sub-components can use.

We would like each sub-component to be completely independent from the others and would like to give them the facility to access the boot loaders registrations and also their own sub-components registrations, so that the sub-components cannot overwrite/accidental modify the main container (which could mess up other sub-components)

To achieve this I was hoping to create a Windsor container in the sub-component using the main container as basis for it and then let the sub-components container take over the responsibility of component management completely. But there is no constructor on a Windsor Container to allow this.

Is this possible?

Am I thinking about things incorrectly and need to approach it from a different angle?

Comment: Have you checked SubContainers? It should be what you need - have one main container, pass it to modules, register a subcontainer from each module, modules register items in subcontainers, but thanks to the link between container/subcontainer modules can also resolve registrations from the main container.

Comment: Yep, they are going to be removed from castle soon (apparently), so did not want to go down that route, but will investigate it further just to make sure.

Comment: That's strange. I've found one more mention on the web that it is deprecated, but even the latest xml for the castle does not mark AddChildContainer as deprecated. If you find more, please post a link here. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jakub, her's the link http://kozmic.net/2010/06/01/castle-windsor-and-child-containers/

Comment: I see. That article has two followups (linked on the bottom). The last one is this. http://kozmic.net/2010/06/03/castle-windsor-and-child-containers-empire-strikes-back/ that should clear the issue a little :-)

Answer (score 0):

As spotted by @Jakub, [this thread](http://kozmic.net/2013/02/17/on-windsor-3-2-release/#disqus_thread) show that child containers are not leaving Castle.